# Creating a DbContext with custom constructor with injected parameter in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working on a code first database, but when I try to do "Update-Database" I get the following error.

```
The target context 'AllMid.DL.Repository.Implementation.AllMidContext' is not constructible. 
Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory.
```

Now it is apparent to me that the problem is that I don't have a default constructor or a an implementation of the IDbContextFactory interface, but in the sample project I am using I am seeing this done without either. Does anyone know how to go about this?

I currently have a DbContext resembling this.

```
internal class AllMidContext : DbContext, IAllMidContext
{
    public DbSet<TreeEntity> Tree { get; set; } 

    public AllMidContext(IConfigurationAccess configAccess) : base(configAccess.GetDefaultConnectionString())
    {
    }
}
```

The configAccess should be being injected by structure map.

and a DataContextAccess class like this

```
    internal class DataContextAccess : IDataContextAccess
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationAccess _configAccess;

        public DataContextAccess(IConfigurationAccess configAccess)
        {
            _configAccess = configAccess;
        }

        public IAllMidContext GetAllMidContext()
        {
            return new AllMidContext(_configAccess);
        }
    }
```

Now the question is is there a way to do this without a default constructor or a factory? My dependency injection will always input the parameter so how can I get EF to use my custom constructor?

Comment: I am more interested in getting it to use my customer constructor with an injected dependency than creating a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `update-database` is looking for a constructor with no input. what you can do is to write a constructor with no inputs and do your injection in its body.